# Migrate projects(VMs) to another GCP account to use free tier

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

My free tier usage is expiring soon and I want to keep the two VMs that I use for testing purposes. Is there a way that I can migrate/move/transfer the VMs to another new GCP account to stay under free tier? I've checked the GCP documentation and it says we have to contact Google support to do so...... but do I really tell the support I want to transfer because I don't want to pay and want to stay in the free tier range?

How can I migrate to another GCP account to stay under free tier?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [SO is not for customer service-related questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: @Martheen "Is there a way that I can migrate/move/transfer the VMs to another new GCP account to stay under free tier?" How is it considered as customer service related question?

Answer (score 2):

As per this [github](https://github.com/vanberge/gce-migrator) you can migrate VM from one project to another project. In order to do that take machine image of the instance and deploy new VM using that images on the destination project.

Comment: Tried this but produced an error. ```./gce-migrate.sh: No such file or directory```

Comment: @CuppaCoffee after cloning the github link to your machine you need to enter the directory using the command 'cd gce-migrator' then you are able to run './gce-migrator.sh' the script.

Comment: Yes. ```cd gce-migrator``` I think there is an error in the source.. it says ```gce-migrate.sh``` but the file in the directory is ```gce-migrator.sh```. However ```gce-migrator.sh```doesn't work either

Comment: For me it showing this:

$./gce-migrator.sh

ERRORS FOUND IN ARGUMENTS - One or more required arguments not found
See help:
GCE MIGRATOR HELP
  Use format ./gce-migrate.sh -s <sourceproject ID> -d <destproject ID> -n <network> -m <migration-type>
      <sourceproject ID>: The project ID (not the name) where VM currently lives
...........

  Examples:
      ./gce-migrate.sh -s sourceproject1 -d destproject1 -n default -m myvm1
      ./gce-migrate.sh -s sourceproject1 -d destproject1 -n static -m myvm1 -S
      ./gce-migrate.sh -s sourceproject1 -d destproject1 -n default -m bulk

Comment: i have this error too. the script does not work.

Comment: Script works! but have issue with service account:

./gce-migrator.sh -s test1 -d test2 -n default -m bulk

Project test1 verified

Project test2 verified
Checking destination network default
Network verified successfully
Checking if we are already in this project...

Your active configuration is: [cloudshell-26768]
Already in test1, continuing!
Validated command arguments... Beginning using method bulk
Looking for GCE service account in destination project...
Listed 0 items.
cannot find service account, exiting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226680/discussion-between-mahboob-and-cuppacoffee).